# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: magento-1.5.1

i am working on magento 1.5 i am getting this error

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1173

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1173

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1173

Notice: Undefined index: _resource_singleton/core/store in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 258